# The university does not want me to include my advisor's name on my PhD dissertation

Tags: phd, advisor, ethics

My advisor is leaving academia and I will graduating and writing a dissertation on the work that I have done in his lab under his supervision. I have no problem to include him on my dissertation but the university is not allowing me to do that.

Will it be misconduct if I did not list him as a contributor in my dissertation?

Comment: This sounds like a very strange situation. I don't think anybody could give you useful advice based on the information you've provided.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Unfortunately, I do not think that we can possibly answer your question here as it depends on your university’s guidelines and what *mentioning as a contributor* signifies according to the university’s rules. For example, at my university, people aren’t mentioned as contributors in a dissertation at all. It may be that your question becomes answerable, if you [edit] in further details, but I doubt that.

Comment: Is it possible that the university simply doesn't want your advisor to be listed in the "examiners/reviewers" list? You can always mention your advisor (and his/her influcence on the thesis) in the acknowledgements page at the very least. If your thesis is based on publications with your advisor, then you will also mention that anyway.

Comment: I disagree with the closing reason that has been given, since the OP is not asking about policy, but about its ethical implications for themselves. I think it is only unclear what is being asked because of the terminology of "contributor."  I *think* that what this means is not listing the advisor officially as supervisor or committee member (and that's what my answer assumes).  If the OP will clarify that, then I think this question can be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

If your university requires you to list a different person as thesis advisor, then that's what you need to do---rightly or wrongly, your university determines its policy there, and you need to follow it.

You, however, can certainly make the contributions of your former advisor clear in the acknowledgements.  As with many ethical questions, this can be safely navigated by the application of sunshine: if you clearly state your former advisor's contributions in the acknowledgements, along with the reason that they are not listed as your advisor, then you should not have any trouble with people thinking that you unfairly chose to exclude them.

Note also, that if you later make any peer-reviewed publications out of this work, then if it would be appropriate to list your advisor as a co-author, you can and should do that.

Answer (score 0):

A PhD thesis is supposed to be independent research undertaken by the candidate. This means there should be only one author, regardless of the status of your supervisor within the university.

However, each thesis should have in the front material a page that lists the committee members (and their signatures!) to prove that the thesis has satisfied the rules of the department/faculty/university. It would be most unusual for the university to insist the name of your supervisor be taken off this list.

In addition, of course, you are free to acknowledge any and all assistance you received along the way.

Comment: From the description in the question it sounds as though another faculty member has been appointed to take over as the advisor of this student since the former advisor is no longer a faculty member.  Under those circumstances you'd list the committee as it existed at the time the thesis was defended, and you could also acknowledge the former advisor in the acknowledgements section.

Comment: At least the "and their signatures!" bit seems to be a highly university-specific statement. I have never seen a thesis that had to be signed by anyone other than the author him- or herself, if at all.